# NUnit VS Adapter 2 is not finding my tests

Tags: c#, nunit

Maybe someone have had same problems with Nunit testing. I have downloaded Nunit and Nunit adapter, I write some code and few unit tests, but it says:

```
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,4917596) ==========
```

Maybe you could tell me some ideas, how to fix it?

I read few tutorials it says I should use test explorer, and it automatically integrates my test. But nothing happens, maybe problem is in that I use 3.0.1 version Nunit?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers\n");
            int number1;
            int number2;
            number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
            int x = helper.Add(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum of " + number1 +
                " and " + number2 + " is " + x);
            Console.ReadKey();
            int y = helper.Subtract(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe difference between " +
                  number1 + " and" + number2 + "  is " + y);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MathsHelper
    {
        public MathsHelper() { }
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            int x = a + b;
            return x;
        }

        public int Subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            int x = a - b;
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
            int result = helper.Add(20, 10);
            Assert.AreEqual(30, result);
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void SubtractTest()
        {
            MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
            int result = helper.Subtract(20, 10);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, result);
        }
    }
}
```

packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Ok, you "write some code and few unit tests", could you show it?

Comment: @gabba I added it, also added packages what I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Nunit 3, you have to use appropriate test adapter available in NuGet as `NUnit3TestAdapter`.

```
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.0.8-ctp-8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Notice it is still in pre-release at present time, so you have to turn on "Include pre-releases" checkbox in NuGet Manager GUI to see it or use `–IncludePrerelease` option in package manager console.

Comment: okey, but if I want to use released stuff, how to make it work. I can't find old versions of Nunit in Nuget. It is working with your solution, thanks.

Comment: Of course you can use older versions of NUnit, and yes - they are still in NuGet repository. Just have a look at "version" dropdown in GUI when you've selected NUnit package, or use `-Version` option in package manager console.

Comment: You see, when I click on version dropdown, there is only 3.0.1 version :)

Comment: Well, I don't know the reason for this to happen. Probably you have outdated NuGet in your VS. Try to check Tools->Extensions and Updates if there's update for NuGet available.

Comment: I just started new project with new test and all versions magically appeared :) So, I can use Unit adapter 2.0 with Nunit 2.6?

Comment: You should be able to use it. Anyway, just check and you'll see.